# JAXB generates duplicate ObjectFactory for package already in episode

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc

I'm using JAXB to generate classes for a schema that imports other schemas.
I'm using maven and configured the maven-jaxb2 plugin to use dependencies as episodes, to skip generating classes for imported schemas.

Nevertheless, JAXB keeps generating the ObjectFactories for imported schemas, resulting in classloader conflicts and misbehaviour at runtime.

As a workaround, I'm using the maven-antrun-plugin to clean up those extra files.
Is there a better way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Ah my good old maven-antrun-plugin is still being used ;-)

Comment: If you're using [this](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation), then it looks like the imported schemas are not recognized as episodes. What does your POM look like?

Comment: @Kenney Not necessarily. Even with episodes, XJC sometimes still generates almost empty `ObjectFactory`.

Answer (score 8):

Even with episodes, XJC sometimes generate some rudimentary `ObjectFactory`. I know this effect and attribute it to a bug in XJC. My workaround so far was exactly the one you're applying, namely `maven-antrun-plugin` with a `delete` task, like [here](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/iso19139-2/gmi/1.0/pom.xml#L96-L114).

But if you get everything generated - despite the episodes - there might be a problem with your configuration. Make sure your episode artifact contain a valid `META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode` with `schemaBindings map="false"` for your package.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Comment: Is there a bug filed at the JAXB project? Will this one ever get fixed? Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are your generated classes dynamic/changing frequently? You could get rid of any generated code that you are no longer using after you generated it once. Sometimes it's even easier to manually write the mapping classes since you can use things like `@XmJavaTypeAdatper`, which the generated code will not have.